# Serial port data through /dev/ttyS0 and file read/write

Tags: linux, serial-port

I recently picked up a serial cable with crossover adapter (Null Modem) and thought it might make an educational experiment to see if I could do some controlled passing and receiving of bytes over it between two Linux (Lubuntu) computers.  I have written some rudimentary code in Java that opens the /dev/ttyS0 "file" as input and output file streams.

I am able to send data back and forth with minicom as well as echo and cat.  I assume the authors of these programs understand what I don't :)  But for some reason, when I try to do the same with this code, the transmit side hangs until there is an LF (ascii 10) character added.  I am thinking the OS is holding the bytes until it has some sort of reason to send a chunk of data...?  Plus, then the receive side reports two copies of the '10' receipt, which I really just don't understand.

For some reason I am thinking that if I write a byte, one should immediately show on the other side, but this is not the case.

As I said, this is just an explorative exercise with no real end game other than a better understanding of how the OS interacts with the serial ports...  Thanks for any info!

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class SOtest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SOtest sot = new SOtest();
    sot.rx();    // or sot.tx() for the transmit side
}

public void tx()  {
    FileOutputStream nmoutfile;

    try {
        nmoutfile = new FileOutputStream("/dev/ttyS0");
        nmoutfile.write(49);  //  ascii value 10 still needed...?
        nmoutfile.close();    //  doesn't force value 49 to send

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage().toString());
    }
}

public void rx()  {
    FileInputStream nminfile; 

    try {
        nminfile = new FileInputStream("/dev/ttyS0");

        while (true) {
            System.out.println(nminfile.read());
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage().toString());
    } 
}
}
```

Comment: Nice question! :) I've once achieved this using `C` and `termios.h`. I have no plan how to achieve this using Java. Can only say that it is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the problems you're getting, you shall set up correctly your serial connection on both sides (the termios.h stuff hek2mgl is talking about). You shall not only open the serial chardev as a file, but also set it up.

A good read on the subject is:

- http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Serial-Programming-HOWTO.html

A few stuff about Java and serial ports:

- https://github.com/jbzdak/java-termios
- [Reading from COM port in Java, Error 0x5 at ..\rxtx\src\termios.c(892)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578021/reading-from-com-port-in-java-error-0x5-at-rxtx-src-termios-c892-error)
- http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/31915
- http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/450480/How-communicate-with-serial-port-in-Java

Comment: Thank you.  The reading was exactly what I needed to better understand.  I see now that Linux is setup by default to treat serial ports as terminals, and that is not what I was looking to use them for.  I didn't want to go the API route with Java here (as in JavaComm or RxTx), so I found that using "stty raw -F ttyS0" on both ends sets them up to do exactly what I was thinking they should do and now the program runs as expected...  thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

### PureJavaComm with JTermios and Maven,

an Open Source, pure Java, drop-in replacement for Sun's and RXTX project's JavaComm SerialPort on Mac OS X, Linux and Windows platforms.

JTermiosReadDemo.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import purejavacomm.CommPortIdentifier;
import purejavacomm.NoSuchPortException;
import purejavacomm.PortInUseException;
import purejavacomm.SerialPort;
import purejavacomm.UnsupportedCommOperationException;


public class JTermiosReadDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, PortInUseException, NoSuchPortException, UnsupportedCommOperationException {
        String port = "/dev/ttyUSB0";
        SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort)    CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(port).open(
                JTermiosDemo.class.getName(), 0);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(serialPort.getInputStream());
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
            
        }
        scanner.close();
    }

}
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sparetimelabs</groupId>
        <artifactId>purejavacomm</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.22</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>com.sparetimelabs</id>
        <url>http://www.sparetimelabs.com/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Reference:

- http://www.sparetimelabs.com/purejavacomm/purejavacomm.php
- https://github.com/nyholku/purejavacomm/blob/master/src/jtermios/testsuite/TwoPortSerialTest.java